# How to get more infos about parameters in TYPO3 Class Reference

Tags: typo3, documentation, extbase

This is the TYPO3 Class Reference for the function addTCAcolumns(). Where can we get more infos about the $columnArray?

[image: Example]

Comment: The answer is to look at the [right documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/). As this question is not about programming or too broad I'll suggest to close it.

Comment: I would sugest to create a specific question about what you want to do. That is more in line with SO policies. Questions about where to find documentation typically get closed. I don't agree with this, but that's the policy. Apart from that a better resource might be https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html Please note that api.typo3.org is currently only availabe for version 8 and below.

Answer (score 2):

Use the full TYPO3 TCA documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/#

You can switch the TYPO3 version in the left column at the bottom.